# Ubuntu 20.04 GCP VM SSH Text suddenly turned bold and cursor is misplaced!

Tags: ssh, 20.04

I have a VM on Google Cloud Platform [Ubuntu 20.04]
Suddenly, all the text has turned bold and the cursor position is misplaced and I am unable to type easily!

[image]

[image]

Everything is messed up in the SSH as if I have randomly coded some CSS.
The cursor position is annoying when you are trying to edit the commands.
All of this happened overnight so I don't know what actually happened!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with 20.04 VMs provisioned on GCP today.

It seems I have this workaround: when starting a second SSH the screen resets on the first session and the cursor is then again well aligned (but the new one is not, at least until you start a third session)

When starting 2 sessions just after each other, it seems both come up working. Maybe they reset each other ?!?.

This only a workaround. I too would like a permanent fix :-)

---

Edit July 13, added screenshot
[Click to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSGtz.png)

Comment: Hi Dharmaraj,
Not sure what you mean "dark text"?
In you original post you state that text turns bold. And your screenshot shows white text (same as on my SSH session)

Comment: Actually no, the text is way MORE BOLD than it used to be.. idk must be a change in GCP?

Comment: I agree, probably GCP.
BUT, it seems to be fixed today. Hurray :-)

Comment: Looks like not for me .... :(